# Android - Оптимизация кода

Tags: оптимизация, android, java

Здравствуйте! Я вывожу на экран задний фон, который будет медленно прокручиваться (как в Parallax Scrolling), размер прокручиваемого изображения 16к+ на 720 пикселей (7мб). При запуске на мощных устройствах показывает FPS 29 (HTC One), а на дешёвых китайских планшетах всего лишь 3 FPS (Texet TM-7024), а потом и вовсе выкидывает. Пожалуйста, помогите, как ещё можно оптимизировать этот код? Прикладываю весь код класса, в котором идёт прокрутка.

---

```
package ru.zein4.g_break.views;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class background_menu extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    GameThread thread;
    int screenW;
    int screenH;
    int bgrW;
    int bgrH;
    int bgrScroll;
    int dBgrY; //Скорость прокрутки background'a
    Bitmap bgr, bgrReverse;
    boolean reverseBackroundFirst;

    long timeNow;
    long timePrev = 0;
    long timePrevFrame = 0;
    long timeDelta;

    Paint exPaint = new Paint();

    Rect fromRect1, toRect1, fromRect2, toRect2;

    public background_menu(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public background_menu (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public background_menu (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inPreferenceConfig = Bitmap.Config_RGB565
        bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.so_large_background, op);

        reverseBackroundFirst = false;

        //инициализируемся
        bgrScroll = 0;  //Начальная позиция прокрутки
        dBgrY = 1; //Скорость прокрутки

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        setFocusable(false);

        exPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
exPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;

        bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w * 2, h, true);
        bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
        bgrH = bgr.getHeight();

        //Делаем второй отзеркаленный битмап
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(-1, 1); //Отражение по горизонали
        bgrReverse = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, bgrW, bgrH, matrix, true); //Создаём битмап из отзеркаленной матрицы
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        fromRect1 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrW - bgrScroll, bgrH);
        toRect1 = new Rect(bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);

        fromRect2 = new Rect(bgrW - bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);
        toRect2 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrScroll, bgrH);

        if (!reverseBackroundFirst) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect1, toRect1, exPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgrReverse, fromRect2, toRect2, exPaint);
        }
        else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect2, toRect2, exPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgrReverse, fromRect1, toRect1, exPaint);
        }

        if ((bgrScroll += dBgrY) >= bgrW)
        {
            bgrScroll = 0;
            reverseBackroundFirst = !reverseBackroundFirst;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    class GameThread extends Thread
    {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private background_menu gameView;
        private boolean run = false;

        public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, background_menu gameView)
        {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.gameView = gameView;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run)
        {
            this.run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder()
        {
            return surfaceHolder;
        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Canvas c;
            while (run)
            {
                c = null;

                //Делаем движение background'a кадронезависимым. Число 16 говорит о том, что максимально допустимый FPS будет 60
                timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timeDelta = timeNow - timePrevFrame;
                if (timeDelta < 16)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(16 - timeDelta);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                timePrevFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try
                {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        synchronized (surfaceHolder)
                        {
                            gameView.onDraw(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Сейчас я посчитал количество оперативной памяти, необходимое для декодирования ресурса:
`16200*720*4 = примерно 47 мб`. 
Где-то слышал, что количество необходимой памяти можно уменьшить, используя `Bitmap.Config_RGB565`. Как применить этот конфиг?

---

**UPDATE** Итак, сейчас прикрутил к битмапу конфиг и сделал рисование без сглаживания, FPS увеличился с 3 до 14 на китайских девайсах. Но всё равно требуется оптимизация.

---

Comment: я андроид тока начал осваивать, но может стоит разделить картинку скажем по (1000х720)х16 и в памяти держать только 3-4 ?

    //-1    
    //текущая
    //+1
    //+2


или толку от этого ноль?

по моим подсчётам это `((47/16)*4)=` 12мб (или 15мб если `+\- 2` блока)

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, я уже пробовал делать что-то вроде этого, но когда нужен был переход между блоками, то на их стыке частенько появлялись и дёргались чёрные полосы.

Comment: может быть просто подгрузка выполнялась последовательно а не параллельно?

или отрисовывалось без кеширования?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, честно скажу, что не помню. Но тогда это здорово потрепало мне нервы...

Comment: а можно  увидеть что это за картинка такая? и что по верх неё будет рисоваться?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat картинку не выложу, а поверх неё будет рисоваться спрайтовая анимация персонажа. Я хотел сделать 2d-бегалку безо всяких С++ и библиотек.

Comment: @SuperCreeper а теперь понятно, вы пытаетесь сделать аля "марио" и задний фон представляете **одной** картинкой, от того она такого безумного разрешения. тогда там точно можно сделать тайлы! (потому я и хотел посмотреть на картинку), и судя по всему когда у вас были чёрные полосы и подёргивания вы каждый элемент поочерёдно выводили, вместо того чтобы, собрать все и потом разом вывести.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat Буду премного благодарен вам за ссылку на какой-нибудь хороший урок по тайлам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исчерпал лимит коментов к вопросу, потому отвечу так.

по непосредственно тайловой графике я хороших статей не видел(да и не искал если честно). Видел  в одной книжке пример тайловой графики, но автор сей книжки заслуженно оскорбляется по всему инету (есть за что).

---

---

---

**велосипед:**

идея тайлов+кеширование (обязательно с кешем!) очень проста

1. создаём объект **`фон`** внутри храним
       общую карту (массив пикселей)
2. создаём объект **`строитель фона`**
       который внутри хранит **`фон`** и размер
       фона в ячейках(N x M), он же хранит
       информацию, о размере ячейки в
       пикселях (и то что не влезет закрасит
       дефолтным цветом)
3. создаём функцию которая вставит тайл
       в ячейку
4. когда все тайлы вставлены одним
       махом рисуем весь массив

приправляем этот **адов супчик** специями  в виде параллельной подгрузки тайлов и т.п. плюшек.

---

---

---

**правильная реализация**

1. берём редактор тайлов (их дохрена!)
       настраиваем  размер в пикселях и
       количество тайлов и чутка рисуем(или
       копипастим).
2. на выходе имеем кучу тайлов,
       отсортированных и распиленных, а так
       же xml документ описывающий карту, в
       особо хороших редакторах ещё и
       xml'ки сетов (дом,мост,дерево, etc)
3. находим библиотеку по работе с
       тайлами (их наверника уже дохрена)
4. пишем адаптер кторый вытаскивает из
       xml'ки порядок тайлов и пихает в
       библиотеку вместе с самими тайлами

мелкие остатки (те что нельзя разрезать на тайлы) заливам растягивающимся изображением (9Patch)

так же в нормальной библиотеке будет реализована тайловая анимация и может даже объединение N-х тайлов в один.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не сделать 10-20 изображений, и поло;ить их в контрол, который за вас будет решать проблемы с памятью? (например `ListView`)

Comment: Потому что потом на этом SurfaceView планируется рисовать другие объекты. А разделять такое огромное изображение на куски будет ещё сложнее.

Comment: Проблема в том, что либо вы уменьшаете изображение (потеря качества), либо пытаетесь представить его в виде коллекции. Как еще один "не очень красивый вариант" - попробудете засунуть изображение в webview, а остальные операции делать на другом слое. Но поставьте перед собой вопрос о правильности самой идеи.

Answer (score 0):

Этот фон какой то особенный? Или там есть последовательности?

1. Можете посмотреть в сторону 9Patch.
2. И еще один совет. Сделайте максимально сжатую jpge картинку. Я думаю что PNG вам просто не нужен, так как у вас и так заполнена вся область.
3. Также рекомендую посмотреть на старых устройствах 2.3. Скорее всего там сразу будет OutOfMemory.
4. Разбейте картинку на тайлы и используйте их.

Comment: На телефоне с 2.1 не выкидывает с обновлённым кодом